# Vaadin Flow 24 - Integer to String Column Render

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

**REVISED QUESTION:**

I know that there is a simple answer to this - so please forgive the newbie question. I've been struggling with a way to display "Yes" or "No" in a grid based on an Integer value of 1 or 0 in the DB. I tried this and got "Integer cannot be converted to boolean":

```
Grid.Column<SJRolesQA> isAncillaryColumn = grid.addColumn(SJRolesQA -> SJRolesQA.getIsAncillary() ? "Yes" : "No")
```

Comment: Please focus on a single question; add two questions if you must.

Comment: What does "complained" and "does not work" mean? Please be specific; if
you get stack traces or error logs, please add them. If the behaviour is
not what you are expecting, please describe it.

Comment: 1 == SJRolesQA.getIsAncillary() ? "Yes" : "No"

Comment: @Knoobie - awesome! You are a gentleman and a scholar!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Knoobie had the answer:

```
1 == SJRolesQA.getIsAncillary() ? "Yes" : "No"
```

It turned out that the data had a null in it - so I reversed the argument:

```
 Grid.Column<SJRolesQA> isAncillaryColumn = grid.addColumn(SJRolesQA -> (null == SJRolesQA.getIsAncillary() || 0 == SJRolesQA.getIsAncillary()) ? "No" : "Yes")
```